# Does _.pluck preserves the original index of the "plucked" array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a mongoDB document with an array of objects field looking like this:

```
"leaving_users" : [
        {
            "user_id" : "FZ78Pr82JPz66Gc3p",
            "leaving_date" : ISODate("2015-06-12T14:14:14.501Z")
        }
    ]
```

Can I use `_.pluck` to obtain the `leaving_date` related to a specific `user_id`?

My code seems to work fine but I wanted to check this is the right way to do it, and be sure that I won't end up sometimes with a different index if I use a `_.pluck` function.

Here is my code:

```
if (doc.leaving_users //guarding
    //if the user belongs to the leaving_users object array
    &&  _.pluck(doc.leaving_users, "user_id").indexOf(userId) != -1 
    //if his leaving_date field is after yesterday
    && doc.leaving_users[_.pluck(doc.leaving_users, "user_id").indexOf(userId)].leaving_date > yesterday)
                {
                    leftRecently  = true;
                }   else{
                    leftRecently  = false;
                }
```

Bonus question: how would you make that more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the indexes will be the same. This is clear if you look at [the implementation of `_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-34):

```
_.pluck = function(obj, key) {
  return _.map(obj, _.property(key));
};
```

...and [the implementation of `_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-21):

```
_.map = _.collect = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
  var keys = !isArrayLike(obj) && _.keys(obj),
      length = (keys || obj).length,
      results = Array(length);
  for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
    var currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
    results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
  }
  return results;
};
```

---

That said, I wouldn't call `_.pluck` twice like that, and I don't think I'd use `_.pluck` for this at all, I'd use [`_.findIndex`](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex) and save the result:

```
var index;
if (doc.leaving_users //guarding
    //if the user belongs to the leaving_users object array
    && (index = _.findIndex(doc.leaving_users, function(e) { e.user_id === userId; }) !== -1)
    //if his leaving_date field is after yesterday
    && doc.leaving_users[index].leaving_date > yesterday)
                {
                    leftRecently  = true;
                }   else{
                    leftRecently  = false;
                }
```

Comment: And do you think my approach is efficient/elegant? Should I do all these tasks like that?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet: Oddly, I was just editing in something about that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice answer. I validate it.